# Javascript getting property of parent inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calls different functions inside of itself. I need the inner functions to access a property of the parent function. The code looks like this:

```
function runFuncWithExtraProperty(fn) {
    fn.insertedProperty = 'myProperty';
    fn();
}
```

I need the functions that run inside of `fn` to be able to access the property I set on `fn`. `fn` could look like this:

```
function fn() {
    () => {
        console.log(this.insertedProperty);
    };
}
```

Does anyone know how I would accomplish something like this so I can add extra properties that can be used by the inner functions? Thanks!

Comment: Use `console.log(fn.insertedProperty)`?

Comment: why not pass them as input parameters?

Comment: You're attaching the property to the function object. To access it, use the function object itself: `console.log(fn.insertedProperty);`. The keyword `this` doesn't refer to the function object. With that said, it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not use an argument?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the console.log never gets called. Below, I make it get called, and I change `this` to `fn`:

```js
function fn() {
    (() => {
        console.log(fn.insertedProperty);
    })();
}

function runFuncWithExtraProperty(fn) {
    fn.insertedProperty = 'myProperty';
    fn();
}

runFuncWithExtraProperty(fn);
```